# How do I convert AddressField "Administrative Area" abbreviation to full name

Tags: commerce, entities

The [Address Field](http://drupal.org/project/addressfield) module automatically converts administrative area (i.e., State/Province) abbreviations to full names on node display.  I need to do this in my own custom module but can't find the function that the Address Field module uses to do this.  How can it be done?

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/34163/5147  This answer on a related question may give you some hints...

Comment: Thanks for the link to that (I answered that one!), the problem is that something like country_get_list() doesn't exist for state/provinces, but something like that is exactly what I'm looking for!

Comment: It seems like this should be a hook or at least a standalone function in addressbook.module but it doesn't look like it is.  Might end up being a feature request.

Comment: The Location Taxonomize module also has a function that does this at line 109 of location_taxonomize_af.module.  I don't understand what's going on there but it may help in finding the solution.

Comment: @PatrickKenny Have a look at the `addressfield_format_address_generate()` function in `plugins/format/address.inc`. The abbreviation -> full name mapping seems to be hard coded into that function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned earlier, there's no function in addressfield that does this, it's hard coded and not re-usable.  Instead, there's a function in addressfield_tokens module which DOES do this.

Using this function isn't really good practice because it's not an official hook (so it could change at anytime without notice), but as long as you're aware of what's going on and you use the proper checks that the module exists, it's the most flexible way to make this happen.  Here's how to use it:

First, ensure that [addressfield_tokens.module](http://drupal.org/project/addressfield_tokens) is installed.  Then you can use this function from line 338 in the .module file:

```
_addressfield_tokens_state($country, $state)
```

You need the $country because abbreviations are sometimes the same for different countries.  So, if we wanted to find the full name of California, we would do this:

```
$california_fullname = _addressfield_tokens_state('US', 'CA')
return $california_fullname;
```

Comment: Can this works with Facets ?

Answer (score 4):

Drupal 8,

For Country List

`$full_country_list = \Drupal::service('country_manager')->getList();`

State or Administrative_area list

`$full_state_list = \Drupal::service('address.subdivision_repository')->getList(['US']);`

Hope, it will be helpful to someone.

Comment: Thank you @allabakash.g This is very useful in 2024.

Answer (score 1):

For someone who wants to convert the country name as well, use:

```
_addressfield_tokens_country($country)
```

Answer (score 1):

Address field contains a very useful function:

```
addressfield_get_administrative_areas($country);
```

This returns the administrative areas for the country specified, keyed by the abbreviations.

e.g.

```
$australian_states = addressfield_get_administrative_areas('AU');
```

This would result in the following array:

```
$australian_states = array(
   'ACT' => t('Australian Capital Territory'),
   'NSW' => t('New South Wales'),
   'NT' => t('Northern Territory'),
   'QLD' => t('Queensland'),
   'SA' => t('South Australia'),
   'TAS' => t('Tasmania'),
   'VIC' => t('Victoria'),
   'WA' => t('Western Australia'),
);
```

Comment: This is the function that you need to use with newer versions of Address Field. The function `_addressfield_tokens_state` mentioned in the accepted answer is no longer available.

Comment: Also, it looks like you need to call `module_load_include('inc', 'addressfield', 'addressfield.administrative_areas');` when `addressfield_get_administrative_areas` isn't defined.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at example/plugins/format/addressfield-example.inc. This file handles all the formatting changes. These look like they're hardcoded in.

Take a look at plugins/format/address.inc as well.

Answer (score 0):

### Background

I needed to output the Province code as the full Province name as well. I dug into the module and in `addressfield.address_formats.inc` I found the following comment:

```
- render_administrative_area_value: True if the value should be rendered
```

I also found the following in address.inc:

```
'#render_option_value' => $address_format['render_administrative_area_value'],
```

From this, it appears that, if you retrieve the render array for the addressfield for a given entity, you can simply set the `administrative_area` sub-field's `#render_option_value` attribute to `TRUE`. I did this (code sample below) and, lo and behold, the Addressfield default formatter is observing this attribute nicely. I've got the full province name just as I wanted.

**PS:** I am making use of entity and uuid_entity modules to store some static content that needs to be version controlled in code and made deployable - thus, instead of `node_load($nid)` you see `entity_load_single_by_uuid('node', $somvar['uuid']);` in the code sample below.

### Code Sample

```
$node = entity_load_single_by_uuid('node', $somvar['uuid']);
$address = field_view_value(
  'node',
  $node,
  'field_address_primary',
  $node->field_address_primary[LANGUAGE_NONE][0],
  'default'
);
$address['locality_block']['administrative_area']['#render_option_value'] = TRUE;

return render($address);
```

Hope this proves useful!